# Jetty / Shiro initialization error 2013-06-01 03:37:23.574:WARN:oejj.ObjectMBean:main:

Tags: java, jetty, warnings, shiro

I have been working on a Java .war web app served by jetty.  I am in the process of integrating Shiro for user authentication/authorization.  Everything was going fine until it came time to hook up the MySql server to a Jdbc realm.  After adding a jetty-web.xml for the first time I had lots of problems with my embedded jetty server.  Complaints about WebAppContext not being the same class as WebAppContext.

I simply removed jetty and all references to it to solve my class miss matching problems.  My webapp now loads and the MySql backing even works, but I am getting a ton of warnings.  It looks like they are coming from somewhere in jetty and I'm not sure how to track down the issue.  Any help figuring out where this is coming from would be appreciated.  Here is a sample of the warnings I am getting.  Code fragments below.

```
2013-06-01 03:55:36.715:WARN:oejj.ObjectMBean:main:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/jmx/ObjectMBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean.mbeanFor(ObjectMBean.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.beanAdded(MBeanContainer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.manage(ContainerLifeCycle.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1236)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean.mbeanFor(ObjectMBean.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.beanAdded(MBeanContainer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.manage(ContainerLifeCycle.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1236)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:99)
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="false"
version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hostingcleveland.beweilder.webTransponder.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ddbTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hostingcleveland.beweilder.webTransponder.dynamoDbTestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ddbTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ddbt/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>alertSend</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hostingcleveland.beweilder.webTransponder.alertsSend</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>alertSend</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/alerts/send/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<resource-ref>
    <description>MySql Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/hcleDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

jetty-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="hcleDB" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/hcleDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/hcle_sec</Set>
            <Set name="User">xxx</Set>
            <Set name="Password">xxx</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting this now as well. It is very strange how an org.eclipse.jetty.jmx NoClassDefFoundError is being thrown but the stacktrace involves that very class. I can tell it has something to do with classloaders, but there is where my knowledge ends.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with the maven jetty plugin, version : 8.1.10.v20130312, and with the inclusion of apache-cxf 2.7.13 into my classpath with maven pom.xml. When removing the library cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty, it solves the problem. This library use some jetty class and i suppose it has a dependency to a different version of jetty, and as Steven said in the comment it has something to do with the classloaders (the one for WEB-INF\lib and the one for the server). 
Here is the maven dependency i removed to solve my problem :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

So it depends on your classpath. It probably has another jetty version included.